# Filter the number of occurrences through a list of sets

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of sets:

```
a = [{'foo','cpu','phone'},{'foo','mouse'}, {'dog','cat'}, {'cpu'}]
```

Expected outcome:

I want to look at each individual string, do a count and return everything `x >= 2` in the original format:

```
a = [{'foo','cpu','phone'}, {'foo','mouse'}, {'cpu'}]
```

I tried looping with a list comprehension but it doesn't work with lists of sets:

```
a = [k for k in a if a.count(k) >= 2]
```

Comment: Again, what is the rule? why there is `phone` in the expected output?

Comment: 'foo' and 'cpu' appear 2 times, so the entire set is returned

Comment: `>` is not the same as `>=`

Comment: also, `a.count(k)` is looking for the exact same as `k`. So if the list was `[{'foo','cpu','phone'},{'foo','cpu'}, {'dog','cat'},{'foo','cpu','phone'}]`, your result would be `[{'foo', 'cpu', 'phone'}, {'foo', 'cpu', 'phone'}]`

Comment: `mouse` only appears once, why is it returned in the desired output? If any element of the set appears 2 or more times in any of the sets then the entire set should be in the output?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
for a_set in a:
    # First we create a counter with counts for all words
    counter.update(a_set)
result = []
for a_set in a:
    for word in a_set:
        if counter[word] >= 2:
            # If any word in any set has a count of 2 or more we append the set
            result.append(a_set)
            break
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

a = [{'foo','cpu','phone'},{'foo','mouse'}, {'dog','cat'}, {'cpu'}]
x = Counter(sum([list(i) for i in a], []))
z = [a for a, b in dict(x).items() if b >=2]
res = []
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        if j in z: 
            res.append(i)
            break 
print(res)
```

Output

```
[{'foo', 'phone', 'cpu'}, {'foo', 'mouse'}, {'cpu'}]
```